# Hackathon Magento Honey Spam , on a custom form?

Tags: magento-1.9

I have been having the problem with spam bots constantly filling "ask a question about the product" form on our product page (this send us an email of the question).  Most as recommend "Hackathon Magento Honey Spam" which I installed, but when I went to test it, the guide says:

> After the Installation you should be able to find an input field with the id="url" in the Customer Register and in the Product Review Form, which should be hidden with our JS.

But I can't find any "url" in the form, so does not seem to be working right (but the options for the honeypot are showing in the back end.  Can this be used for other forms other than contact and newsletter?

Update: Found this on Github closed issues

> Add something like this to your layout XML so that the HoneySpam template is loaded in your form_fields_before section. Then, you may have to implement something like this if your contact form does not use the default contacts/index/post route.

https://github.com/magento-hackathon/HoneySpam/issues/26